# Transferring data from Postgres 9.6.5 to Postgres 11.7 on Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a Postgres 9.6.5 Docker container that has a volume associated with it for the /var/lib/postgresql/data folder. I need to upgrade Postgres to version 11.7 and preserve the data present on the old version.
I tried to attach the data present in the volume, but it gives the following error.

[image]

I read in the Postgres documentation that it is possible to upgrade an old version to a newer one when it is installed on a physical machine, however the procedure seems not to exist in the case of containers. So far the only working way I have found for data recovery is via dump file, which, however, may be inefficient in the presence of a lot of data. I have seen that there is also a kind of direct dump between containers (i.e., without going through file.sql), using the following command

```
docker exec id_container_old_postgres pg_dump -U postgres -d db_name | docker exec -i id_container_new_postgres psql -U postgres -d db_name
```

This did not work for me and gave the following error

```
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

However, even this method I am afraid is inefficient. Therefore, I think it would be much more useful to find a way to get Postgres 11.7 to read data directly from the volume. Is there any way to do this and any data retrieval procedure that is more efficient than the one I mentioned?

Comment: have you tried to restore from the dump ?

Comment: Yes, I used the command docker exec -it container_id pg_dump -U postgres -d db_name > dump.sql to export the data  and then, within the container, the command psql db_name < dump.sql to import data. It worked, but as I said, it is not efficient if there is a lot of data. @LarsNielsen

Answer (score 3):

Given where you are starting from (you don't know how to connect to postgresql at the moment) no.

You aren't going to be doing this repeatedly, so focus on doing it simply and correctly.

Firstly, postgresql 11 is end-of-life, so unless you *have* to use that version, use a later one.

Secondly, user the newer version of `pg_dump` not the older one. The new version knows all about older versions and can translate where required.

So:

- If possible upgrade to PostgreSQL 16 (the latest)
- Install the PostgreSQL client package v16 on your host
- Use that to dump with `-Fc` (custom/compressed format) to a file
- Then use it to restore to a container with PostgreSQL 16 too
- Delete the file